# How to change mediaelementjs audio player container height?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, mediaelement.js, mediaelement

I'm using WordPress to output a [mediaelementjs](http://mediaelementjs.com/) audio player. The audio player's `mejs-container` is given an inline style of `height 30px`. The code that does this is located in file `wp-includes/js/mediaelement/mediaelement-and-player.min.js`. For example:

```
ioHeight:30
```

I tried overriding the height in my style sheet but that doesn't work because the inline style takes precedence.

How can I change this height?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating the mediaelement you can use the option `audioHeight`

```
  $('audio').mediaelementplayer({
    audioWidth: '100%',
    audioHeight: 30
  });
```

Afterwards, you can access the player using the following JS:

```
$('audio')[0].player
```

That will allow you to change the size of the player using the function

```
$('audio')[0].player.setPlayerSize(width,height);
```

This function will change the size of the player but leave the controls as they were so you'll need to adjust their size as well using the function:

```
$('audio')[0].player.setControlsSize();
```

Comment: Problem is, mediaelement is already created by WordPress. Do you know if there is a way of filtering the height that's already been set?